# Ubuntu 16.04 ATI Radeon HD 5450 Graphics Support

Tags: lts, gpu, amd-processor, 16.04, gpu-driver

In 16.04 LTS support for AMD proprietary drivers has been dropped. Instead there's an open source AMDGPU driver.
**My Question:** Will the ATI Radeon HD 5450 work with the open source AMDGPU driver?

Comment: Unlikely. It's an old card, and AMD has a hard time keeping up with much newer hardware support.

Comment: The old radeon driver should be available. You card most likely will work. It is very easy to test by LiveUSB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [official release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes#fglrx) of [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com) 16.04 (Xenial Xerus), the open source ADMGPU driver should support most AMD graphics cards, so I can safely say yes, your graphics card should be supported.

However, I do recommend that when the official release of Ubuntu 16.04 comes (April 21), be sure to install using a live disc or a bootable disk to try out Ubuntu 16.04 and see how it performs on that particular machine, before doing a full installation.